# Clickhouse group by with difference less then

Tags: group-by, difference, clickhouse

```
date_start             | date_end               | value
2020-12-05 11:00:00    | 2020-12-05 11:15:00    | 1
2020-12-05 11:15:00    | 2020-12-05 11:30:00    | 2
2020-12-05 11:30:00    | 2020-12-05 11:45:00    | 3
2020-12-05 13:00:00    | 2020-12-05 13:15:00    | 4
```

If the difference of date_start are less than 15 minutes, then group the rows and calculate the sum of values.

Expected result

```
date_start             | date_end               | sum
2020-12-05 11:00:00    | 2020-12-05 11:45:00    | 6
2020-12-05 13:00:00    | 2020-12-05 13:15:00    | 4
```

Comment: look at answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bclickhouse%5D+runningDifference and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bclickhouse%5D+neighbor